# Wireless network and bluetooth adapter problems

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: f8:da:0c:00:fe:2b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
       resources: irq:131 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

Once in a while, Bluetooth says to plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth which is back to normal after a restart. But wifi is always disabled

Tried rfkill unblock all .. didnt work
Rfkill list all shows 
Wireless lan 
Soft and hardblocked as no 
Bluetooth
Soft and hard blocked as no

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: We wonder, then, why it is disabled. Please run and provide a link to the wireless script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: You pasted the script itself, not the results of running the script. Please try again.

Comment: sorry    https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7QQhNTmphn/

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a complete answer as I believe we will have to correct a few things and check again before we reach the solution.

First, we notice that you have a Broadcom wireless driver installed. Your device is a Realtek. Let's remove the incorrect driver:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Second, we notice that both Wicd and Network Manager are installed. New in Ubuntu 17.10 and later is networkd and netplan. Netplan clearly says NM is in charge. From your readings:

```
[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I recommend that you remove Wicd:

```
sudo apt purge wicd*
```

After doing so, tell us if this line remains in NetworkManager.conf

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Does this line remain after removing Wicd?

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlo1
```

If it remains, we will need to edit the file to remove it.

Once these steps are taken, reboot and report back your result and we'll continue if needed.

**EDIT**: Please remove the keyfile section; from the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Remove this section completely:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlo1
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It might take a reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: [keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlo1
the line still remains

Comment: Should i just delete these two lines?

Comment: Yes, as I will suggest in an edit in a few moments.

Comment: No improvements ...  wifi in settings now shows unavailable instead of unmanaged. FYI For once wifi worked today then after reboot it didn't work ( THIS IS BEFORE REMOVING keyfile) . The network was not disabled at that time..  so there is a small probability that my wifi works if I keep rebooting again and again but why??

Comment: Instead of rebooting, does it work with: `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: No immediate effect ... sometimes changes after several hours. I kept my laptop on for a whole night now I get wifi again.. I am not sure if sudo service network-manager restart is the reason it is working now ... but I do remember using it

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gDFCFZV7hq/ in working conditions

Comment: *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: f8:da:0c:00:fe:2b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
       resources: irq:131 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff

Comment: The paste 'in working conditions' doesn't help us analyze what's wrong when it is not working. Please pull a wireless info when it is not and paste it and give us the link.